# How do I make a class take parameters in a certain order?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a quiz creation program in Python 3. One thing that it must do is take parameters in a certain order. How do I achieve this?

The Question class should have a label (variable: name),a question text (variable: text), and a point value (variable points),
and the Question class should take parameters in the following order: the name and the question text from the constructor and assign them to instance variables. The points value should be initialized to 0.0

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Question'
        self.text = 'How are you?'
        self.points = 0.0



class Multiple_Choice(Question):




    def menu():
        print('Commands:')
        print('m - Add Multiple Choice Question')
        print('p - Add Points For a Question')
        print('r - Add Correct Answer for a Question')
        print('t - Print A Test')
        print('q - Quit')


def main():
    print('The Amazing Quiz Database!')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The expected output (for a question on the quiz) is:

How are you? Points 3

a. Great

b. (CORRECT) OK

c. Fair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` needs to specify parameters!

```
def __init__(self, name, text):
    self.name = name
    self.text = text
    self.points = 0.0
```

Now you can create a question object (in the `main` method): `q = Question(name='Question', text='How are you?')`

Comment: How do I add the 'Points' to that?

Comment: @ElliottLambert just add another parameter to the signature of `__init__` e.g. `andfinallypoints`. Then you can pass one more parameter when you call `Question`